# Why is the highest point value (6681') lower than the contour interval value of 7000'?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, departure-sid, symbology

Why is the highest point value (6681') lower than the contour interval value of 7000'? As seen on the chart, the orange areas represent 7000 feet, but there is an obstacle with an altitude lower than 7000 feet in the orange area. If this elevation is not the highest point on the SID chart, why is it shown with the highest point arrow? Detailed information about the Jeppesen chart is available at the top right of the image.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The orange area on the chart means elevation is **between** 5000 and 7000 ft AMSL according to the contour intervals legend. The white area is anything below 5000 ft AMSL. So the highest point of 6681' is within the range for the orange area.